# using Javascript to force number precision on event Onkeypressed in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

what i need is to force user while they are typing in a textbox
  -

1. the maximum number they can put is 16
2. if they press . they can put additional 2 digits after the dots

so what i have done so far is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" Width="200" onkeypress="validateCurrencyX(this,7, 2);" >0.00</asp:TextBox>
```

the javascript code is

```
function validateCurrencyX(sender,prefix, suffix){
var something = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
           var valueArr = something.split('.');

            if (valueArr[1]!= null && valueArr[1].length > suffix-1)
                event.returnValue = false;

            if (valueArr[0].length > prefix-1)
                event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

anyway my code has problems that
 - when i select the whole text, or some part of the text, and press something, it doesn't change anything

is there any ordinary way they do this ?  i'm quite new to both javascript and asp.net
thank you for attention

Comment: What is the `prefix` argument supposed to be?

Comment: @NathanWall Wall prefix is the number available before the dot where i want it to be 16. and the suffix is available number after the dot

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to both javascript and .net, it would be best that you not try to reinvent the wheel.

If you are open to using jQuery, take a look at [NumberFormatter](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter)

```
$(".amt").blur(function(){
    $(this).format({format:"#,###,###,###,###,###.00", locale:"us"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want it to:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" Width="200" oninput="validateCurrencyX(this,7, 2);" onkeydown="validateCurrencyX(this,7, 2);" >0.00</asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
var validateCurrencyX = (function() {
    // Closure for local oldVal variable
    var oldVal = 0;
    return function validateCurrencyX(sender, prefix, suffix) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Convert to number
            var val = sender.value * 1,
            // Get decimals
                dec = sender.value.split('.')[1];
            if(
                val != val // NaN
                || val > 16
                || val < 0
                || dec && dec.length > suffix // check number of decimals
            ) {
                // If the new input doesn't fit the criteria, revert to the old input.
                sender.value = oldVal;
            } else {
                if(Math.floor(val) != 0 && sender.value.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    // If it's a number >= 1, remove leading '0's.
                    sender.value = sender.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
                }
                // Value is good. Save it in case we need to revert later.
                oldVal = sender.value;
            }
        }, 0);
    };
})();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6HUUT/4/

The key to getting a user-friendly real-time text validator is to (1) use **`onkeydown`** / **`oninput`** not `onkeypress` because `onkeypress` doesn't fire for things like paste and delete, and (2) use a `setTimeout` with interval `0` to check what the user *actually* inputs and change it after it is updated in the textbox, rather than trying to prevent them from inputting it at the outset. Again, this helps with things like paste and delete, and also inserting characters in places other than the beginning, and generally makes your life easier. The idea is just to let the user make changes, and then check them to make sure they're ok.

Note, the use of `onkeydown` along with `oninput` is used for legacy browsers. `input` is sufficient for modern browsers, but older browsers (circa IE8) don't support it.

Comment: when press . it not adds additional 2 digits after the dots

Comment: @krish, Couldn't that make things difficult for the user? If you want this feature, you could work out something to get it working *and* user friendly, but you wouldn't just want it to add two 0s and that's it. There is more to consider from a UX point-of-view. Those considerations can be left up to the developer implementing this technique, and is beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is without using javascript since you have said- *is there any ordinary way they do this ?* So just have a look at this:

1) *the maximum number they can put is 16*: for this you have the `maxlength` property of textbox. Set it to **16**

2) This piece of code will restrict your user in entering only 2 digits after the decimal in your textbox.

```
//In key press event of your TextBox:
if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
    TextBox tt = (TextBox)sender;
    if (tt.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1 && tt.Text.Substring(tt.Text.IndexOf('.')).Length >= 3)
     {
       e.Handled = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `[maxlength]` has nothing to do with the maximum value in a text box.

Comment: @zzzzBov: The Op is asking that the maximum number that can be inputted is 16. I have assumed it as a 16 digit number rather than the value 16.  Let me see if I was right. Anyway he can use the answer to the second point which will work fine.

Comment: thanks both. but  @zzzzBov was right..  the 16-didgit requirement mean the number on the left of the '.' only... so setting the attribute isn't gonna help... i think i'll make it clearer on the question